# Eigenvalues for the sum of symmetric matrix and scaled identity matrix in EMMA method

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am studying the derivation of the [EMMA statistical method](https://doi.org/10.1534/genetics.107.080101) and encountered a section of the authors' proof involving spectral decomposition (page 1712) which I do not fully understand. I understand that there is a dedicated statistics Stack Exchange, but my question can be distilled down to a purely mathematical inquiry, so I thought it would be best to ask here.

Briefly, here is the scenario:

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a $(n \times p)$ design matrix housing fixed effects in a linear mixed model (LMM), where $n > p$.

Let $\mathbf{Z}$ be a $(n \times q)$ design matrix housing random effects in an LMM.

Let $\mathbf{K}$ be a $(q \times q)$ positive, semi-definite matrix defining covariances between various individuals.

Let $\textbf{S}=\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{X(X'X)^{-1}X'}$ be a $(n \times n)$ projection matrix which is idempotent and rank deficient.

Now, we construct the product
$$\mathbf{S(ZKZ'} + \delta \mathbf{I)S}$$
where $\delta$ is some constant.

The EMMA authors state that the spectral decomposition of $\mathbf{S(ZKZ'} + \delta \mathbf{I)S}$ can be expressed as
$$\mathbf{S(ZKZ'} + \delta \mathbf{I)S} = \mathbf{U_{SZKZS}} diag(\lambda_1 + \delta, ..., \lambda_p + \delta, 0, ..., 0) \mathbf{U'_{SZKZS}}$$
where $\mathbf{U_{SZKZS}}$ is an eigenvector matrix for the product $\mathbf{SZKZ'S}$ and $\lambda_i$ is the $i$th eigenvalue.

Using [this source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587314/eigenvalues-of-the-addition-of-a-symmetric-matrix-and-the-identity-matrix), I understand how $\mathbf{ZKZ'} + \delta \mathbf{I}$ can be expressed in this form:
$$\mathbf{ZKZ'} + \delta \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{R} + \delta \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{U_R \Sigma_R U'_R} + \delta \mathbf{I} = \mathbf{U_R \Sigma_R U'_R} + \delta \mathbf{U_R I U'_R} = \mathbf{U_R (\Sigma_R} + \delta \mathbf{I) U'_R}$$
It follows then that $\mathbf{S(ZKZ'} + \delta \mathbf{I)S} = \mathbf{S U_R (\Sigma_R} + \delta \mathbf{I) U'_R S}$.

What I don't understand, and this is probably me not understanding some of the nuances in linear algebra, is how does multiplication by $\mathbf{S}$ on either side transform $\mathbf{(\Sigma_R} + \delta \mathbf{I)}$ to $diag(\lambda_1 + \delta, ..., \lambda_p + \delta, 0, ..., 0)$? What is the proof of this? I understand the zeros in the result correspond to the rows in $\mathbf{S}$ that are linearly dependent. How does $\sigma_i + \delta$ get converted to $\lambda_i + \delta$? Much appreciation for any help!